# How to get the list of values for a particular key in a hashmap?

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, hashmap

I have a json1 data as follows -

```
    "data": {
          "user": [
            {
              "id": "5735",
              "items": [
                {
                  "itemId": "698726h",
                  "state": "new"
                },
                {
                  "itemId": "999",
                  "state": "new"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
```

to be compared with the another json2 model as follows -

```
    "entity": {
          "user": [
            {
              "id": "5735",
              "items": [
                {
                  "itemId": "698726h",
                  "state": "old"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
```

In the above jsons user is an array of objects and the Items are also an array of objects. I want to compare the `user.id()` and if it matches then I iterate through the items objects and when the ItemId also matches then the corresponding state attribute is changed from "new" to "old". In the above example the "state" for the "ItemId":"698726h" has been changed from new to old.

In order to achieve the above requirement I have created a hashmap with the keys as the `user.id()` and the corresponding ItemIds will be stored as the array of string as the values for the particular key. When the hashmap is created I compare it to the other json. I search for the key that matches the user.id() of the other json and when it matches I get all the corresponding values or a list of ItemIds for that key. Now I change the state of the ItemIds from "new" to "old" in the other json for the procured list of ItemsIds. In order to achieve the same I have done the following -

```
HashMap<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    json1.data().user().forEach(
      user -> {
        map.put(user.id(),user.items().stream()
          .map(k->k.itemId()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
      }
    );

//Then I iterate through the json2 and compare the key of the hashmap to the user.id() in the json2-

json2.entity().user().forEach(
user ->{
If(map.containsKey(user.id())){
   
 List<String> val = map.get(user.id()); // ERROR //NOT WORKING

//Here I want to fetch all the corresponding itemIds as a list of string as provided in the map.
//After getting the list of itemids, I want to change the state of the corresponding itemIds from "new" to "old".
  }
 }
);
```

The error is -

> Incompatible types.Found 'java.lang.Object', required: 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>'

Is there any alternative solution if this is getting complicated?

Comment: May be a [repost from minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77908760/642706).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
 List<String> val = (List<String>) map.get(user.id());
```